# jQuery nth-child exclude other elements

Tags: jquery

I have some floated div's and I want to select the third with jquery.
Also, after each 3 elements I have a hr tag in my html and this hr is also included by jquery in the nth-child count. Can I select only the divs and exclude the other elements inserted in html?

This is my code

```
$('.col:nth-child(3n)').addClass('third');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the HTML you're working with?

Comment: :) I find out with the help below, thank you anyway! A great community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('div.col:nth-of-type(3n)').addClass('third');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WntR5/

And for <=IE8 (unfortunately as allways)

```
$('div.col').each(function (idx, el) {
  if ((idx + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    $(el).addClass('third');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WntR5/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. The users below told me that this can work also with .eq(2) but it work until the first hr tag, so your solution is the best for me now! Thanks!

Comment: This works great, but the main idea for this is to add this class on IE, because CSS nth selector is not working on IE8 or less. Looks like this is not working also.... any ideea?

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian Mhm, I hoped jQuery would simulate it for browsers not supporting the css3 pseudo class. Seems it's not so ;)   I guess the only solution then, would be to iterator over the elements. I'll give an example shortly. (Code added, have a look)

Comment: This is working great! Thank you so much, I have a lot to learn in jquery/javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `.col` elements are the `div` elements you want to select, you need the `.eq` method instead of `nth-child`:

```
$(".col").eq(2); //Selects the 3rd element with class col
```

Note that if you want to use a selector, you could use the `:eq` selector but the method above is faster.

The problem with [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is that it returns the specified elements *if they match the selector*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.col').eq(2).addClass('third');
```